# How to clear Input data from within JQuery Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple form users can fill out and also add a new form to add multiple entries.

Everything works fine except when I enter data in the first set of inputs and click create new memberships it will take the data from the form and put it in the text boxes.

How can I stop that?

http://jsfiddle.net/811yohpn/2/

I have tried a couple different ways.

```
$('#education').find('input:text').val('');
$('#education: input').val('');
```

However that will clear all entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call find on the newDiv, instead of all inputs within `#education`.

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5hwuzh1/)**

```
newDiv.find('input:text').val('');
```

```js
var ed = 1;

function new_education() {
    ed++;
    var newDiv = $('#education div:first').clone();
    newDiv.attr('id', ed);
    var delLink = '<a class="btn btn-danger" style="text-align:right;margin-right:65px" href="javascript:deled(' + ed + ')" > Delete Education ' + ed + ' </a>';
    newDiv.find('tr:first th').text('Education ' + ed);
    newDiv.append(delLink);
    
    newDiv.find('input:text').val(''); // <----------- added this
    
    $('#education').append(newDiv);
}

function deled(eleId) {
    d = document;
    var ele = d.getElementById(eleId);
    var parentEle = d.getElementById('education');
    parentEle.removeChild(ele);
    //ed--;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<legend>Education</legend>
<div id="education">
    <div id="1">
        <table border=3>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4" style="background-color:#b0c4de;">Education 1</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>School Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="schoolname[]" maxlength="30" size="30"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>Degree Type</label>
                    <input type="text" name="degreetye[]" maxlength="30" size="30"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>Degree Field</label>
                    <input type="text" name="degreefield[]" maxlength="30" size="30"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<br/><a class="js-addNew btn btn-info" href="javascript:new_education()"> Add New Education </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the inputs under the cloned element

```
newDiv.find('input').val('')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zvzb04fm/)

Your selectors are selecting all input elements within the `#education` container, that is not what you want. The `newDiv` variable refers to the newly created element so you can use that to find the input elements within in and then clear it